# Using uninterpret function for log

Tags: z3

I am trying to learn how Z3 uninterpreted functions work to show that `n=2k+1 =>  log(m) + k*log(m*m) == n*log(m)`.  To do so I use something like following

```
mylog = Function('mylog', IntSort(), IntSort())
mylog_rule1 = mylog(x*y) == mylog(x) + mylog(y)
mylog_rule2 = mylog(x**y) == y*mylog(x)
#mylog_rule3 = y*mylog(x) == mylog(x**y)  #is this rule needed ? 



rules = And(mylog_rule1, mylog_rule2, mylog_rule3)
prop = Implies(n==2*k+1, log(m) + k*log(m*m) == n*log(m))
prove(rules, prop)
```

There must be something wrong in my approach because this doesn't quite work.  In fact I can't even do `prove(Implies(mylog(x*y) == mylog(x) + mylog(y), mylog(m*n) == mylog(m) + mylog(n))` which just change the variable names.

Comment: What are the variables x, y, m, n?
Are they quantified? Perhaps you intend to assume quantified formulas that axiomatize properties of log.
Also, your example mixes mylog and log that are two different function symbols

Answer (score 1):

Z3 will not be able to solve this kind of problem effectively.
Z3 has a solver for nonlinear arithmetic ([nlsat](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/leonardo/files/IJCAR2012.pdf)). However, this solver does not support quantifiers and uninterpreted functions. Z3 will support that in the future.
So, when a problem contains uninterpreted functions such as `mylog`, Z3 will use a different (and incomplete) solver for nonlinear arithmetic. This solver will fail on simple nonlinear problems.

Another issue with your example is that you did not use the universal quantifier in your rules.
The simple example `prove(Implies(mylog(x*y) == mylog(x) + mylog(y), mylog(m*n) == mylog(m) + mylog(n))` can be proved even when the incomplete solver for nonlinear arithmetic is used.
Here is the correct Z3Py script ([also available online here](http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/DQhx))

```
mylog = Function('mylog', RealSort(), RealSort())
x, y = Reals('x y')
m, n = Reals('m n')
prove(Implies(ForAll([x,y], mylog(x*y) == mylog(x) + mylog(y)), 
      mylog(m*n) == mylog(m) + mylog(n)))
```